# History of opened windows

Tags: windows, history

I'm looking for a tool, which keeps a history of opened windows. For example if I open the notepad, close it again, the tool should display that `notepad.exe` was closed at which time.

The reason behind this is because I've previously had `cmd.exe` windows pop up, which close themselves rather quickly and I have no way of telling what/why they did. Same goes for applications that launch an action and happen to pop up exactly where I wanted to click, accidentally closing the window.

I've searched for such a thing but couldn't find anything.

Does such a tool exist, can someone recommend anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is an inbuilt mechanism that Windows uses, as and can configure it as mentioned in this post: [How can I get a history of running processes](https://superuser.com/a/1052550/701468) using your group policy editor.

Alternatively you can use this tool from Nirsoft: [LastActivityView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_activity_view.html) or [ExecutedProgramsList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/executed_programs_list.html) depending on your actual needs.

> LastActivityView is a tool for Windows operating system that collects
>   information from various sources on a running system, and displays a
>   log of actions made by the user and events occurred on this computer.
>   The activity displayed by LastActivityView includes: Running .exe
>   file, Opening open/save dialog-box, Opening file/folder from Explorer
>   or other software, software installation, system shutdown/start,
>   application or system crash, network connection/disconnection and
>   more...

and

> ExecutedProgramsList is a simple tool that displays a list of programs
>   and batch files that you previously executed on your system. For every
>   program, ExecutedProgramsList displays the .exe file, the
>   created/modified time of the .exe file, and the current version
>   information of the program (product name, product version, company
>   name) if it's available.